# How to create Nuget Package of Multi Tier application in C# .Net Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget-package

I am trying to create Nuget package for a .net core 2.0 project that uses layered architecture. The Visual Studio solution has more than 2 tiers.

I can create Nuget package with dotnet pack. However, when I try to install the Nuget package that I created, I get error and the installation rollback. I guess, the dotnet pack command is not able to pack all the dependencies.

Currently, this is a major blocker for me as I won't be able to proceed without fixing this. Has anyone had similar experience?

Comment: Have you tried looking at this.. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-pack?tabs=netcore2x

Answer (score 0):

Have you published the nuget package e.g. to nuget.org or local feed. see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/library-guidance/publish-nuget-package

For setting up a local feed - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/local-feeds